# Android SDK platform-tools fails to install on Debian 7

Tags: android, debian, android-sdk-tools

I tried install the Android SDK on Debian 7.0 Wheezy 64bits according to this tutorial:
http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=105734

But when I used android SDK Manager to install the SDK platform-tools, it appeared following errors:

```
Stopping ADB server failed (code -1).
Unable to run 'adb': Cannot run program "/home/ben/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory.
Starting ADB server failed (code -1).
```

Any hints where I could search for this issue ?

Comment: do `/home/ben/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb` exist?

Comment: yes, it exist but unable to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're running 64bit Debian but forgot to install ia32-libs.

Because the phones aren't 64bit, so there is no 64bit version of adb. You need the ia32-libs.

After install the ia32-libs, open Android SDK Manager, then uninstall all the tools and reinstall them.

You should no longer get the adb error.

Answer (score 0):

Download the SDK, unpack and update it with following command:

```
android update sdk --no-ui
```